# GridBagConstraints filling both VERTICAL & HORIZONTAL

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

How do I go about filling both the vertical and horizontal space available in the grid cell of interest?

For example:

```
JTextArea file1 = new JTextArea();
file1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
c.weightx = 1.0 / ELEMENTS_IN_WIDTH;
c.weighty = 0.9;
c.insets = new Insets(PAD, PAD, PAD, PAD);
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
mainPanel.add(file1, c);
```

This fills the cell vertically but not horizontally.

Obviously adding `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL` after the `VERTICAL` value will only override the value of `c.fill`

`OR`'ing them like `c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL | GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL` also doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use:

```
GridBagConstraints gridConst = new GridBagConstraints();
gridConst.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
```

Comment: Yeah thank you... I already found it as I mentioned in the answer... (+1)

Answer (score 2):

I was to hasty and missed the obvious field of `GridBagConstraints.BOTH`. The issue is now resolved... sorry for the false bother.